# Pointwise multiplication on tensor algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, modules, tensor-products

Let $M$ be a $R$-module over commutative ring $R$.
Then we define:
$$T(M)=\bigoplus\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}T^k M = R\oplus M \oplus (M\otimes M)\oplus\dots$$
So that by definition of direct sum elements of $T(M)$ are tuples: $T(M)\ni v = (v_0,v_1,v_2,\dots)$
where $v_0 \in R$, $v_1 \in M$, $v_2 \in M\otimes M$ and so on, such that for all but finite number $v_i=0$.

We also know that there is map: $*:M^{\otimes r}\times M^{\otimes s}\to M^{\otimes (r+s)}$,
 $(m_1\otimes\dots\otimes m_r)*(m'_1\otimes\dots \otimes m'_s) = (m_1\otimes \dots \otimes m_r \otimes m'_1 \otimes \dots \otimes m'_s)$

I am trying to define a multiplication (to make it into algebra) as a map:
$$\times_T:T(M)\times T(M)\to T(M)
\\(v,w)\mapsto v \times_T w$$
But I ran into confusion on how it can be defined:
$$(v \times_X w)=(v_0,v_1,v_2, \dots)\times_X (w_0,w_1,w_2,\dots):=\dots?$$
using components of the tuples.
Is it correct to define it as:
$$\dots =(v_0 * w_0, \quad v_1*w_0 +w_1*v_0 , \quad v_2*w_0+w_2*v_0 + v_1*w_1,\quad \dots)$$
(where $+$ is the addition operation on $T^k M$)
Or it is different?

Comment: That is correct.  Since you are taking the direct sum, only finitely many of the $v_i$ and $w_i$ will be nonzero.  So, the product will exist.  Although, your $w_2 \ast v_0$ should be $v_0 \ast w_2$.

Comment: @JoeJohnson126, Thanks. Is there any way to write down components of resulting tuple more compactly?

Comment: You could use $\sum_{k = 0}^n v_k \ast w_{n - k}$

Comment: @JoeJohnson126 Great! Thank you.